# Detecting a Single Type of Object With MATLAB's Bag of Features?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, feature-detection, matlab-cvst

I've been working with the Bag of Visual Features class in MATLAB and following a number of tutorials, mainly this: http://in.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/image-category-classification-using-bag-of-features.html

So far I have managed to successfully differentiate between two or more different types of objects using the bag of features class. However, also need to be able to class a specific type of object (pre-selected) into one class and ALL OTHER objects into another class, i.e. detect only an object of interest.

The logic I require is as follows:

```
If item is item of interest 

    {

    perform action

    }

Else

    {

    ignore and move on to next image

    }
```

I have tried creating a images containing of blank images in order to form the second group, but this results in my test images being sorted incorrectly to the group to which they have the most features in common.

Is there any way around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should train a two-class classifier: category of interest vs. everything else.

You should create a training set where class1 includes only objects of interest, and class2 includes a wide variety of other objects or backgrounds.